# Why do my tasks match every RabbitMQ queue in a headers exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to implement exponential backoff with a RabbitMQ headers exchange, and I had each queue be bound with `x-match: "all"` and `x-retry-count: [RETRY COUNT FOR THIS LEVEL]`. However, what I found was that if I try to retry a task and I have backoff queues for 100, 200, 400, and 800 millisecond wait time, each task I send to the retry exchange somehow matches every queue.

As you can see in the picture below, for the 200ms backoff queue, I'm binding the header `x-retry-count: 2`, but a task with the header `x-retry-count: 1` is matching it (and the x-retry-count values for all other queues in the backoff exchange too). Why would that be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found what was going on. `x-retry-count` doesn't count as a header that can be matched on because it starts with `x-`; naming the header retry-count does work